# How to pass parameters with replaceScene method in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, view, properties, cocos2d-iphone, scene

when i changed view in Cocoa Touch i use this:

```
GameViewController *game = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameViewController"];
game.something = someValue;
game.somethingOther = someOtherValue;

[self presentViewController:game animated:NO completion:^{}];
```

How can i pass this values before `replaceScene`?

I've got this now:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameLayer scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, that was so easy...

Needed to create method `+(CSScene *)sceneWithParameter:` and method `-(id)initWithParameter:`. And in first method need to change `ClassLayer *layer = [ClassLayer node]` on `ClassLayer *layer = [[ClassLayer alloc] initWithParameter:]` and it works.